# jQueryUI autocomplete response data

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

**SCENARIO**

I have a jQueryUI `autocomplete` in a page. The data are retrieved through an AJAX call. Everything is working fine.

**Question**

As to the [jQueryUI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), the `source` property is a setter.

Is there any autocomplete property exposing the retrieved data?

In other term, if I re-focus the autocomplete bound input and it still contains the previous searched terms, can I show the autocomplete results without re-excuting the ajax call?

I have already searched for similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2240272/sirderpington).
Thanks to [SirDerpington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2240272/sirderpington), I succeed in re-opening the result menu. Still, the AJAX call is re-processed.

```
        $('mySelector').autocomplete().on("focus", function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("search");
        })
```

So the question remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right you want to show the same results if the user re-focusses the input?

In my <kbd>[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/z42Bm/1/)</kbd> it seems to work but I'm not sure if this would trigger an AJAX Call.
Anyway see what I did:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 0
}).focus(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var inputVal = $this.val();
    //just a check to prevent showing all results if inputVal is empty
    if (inputVal !== '') {
        $this.autocomplete("search");
    }
});
```

Notice what the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) say about `search` as method:

> When invoked with no parameters, the current input's value is used.

**EDIT**

Using a sort of "cache" seems to be a good way to solve your issue. Because I can not really use a source I just used jsfiddle's `/echo/json/` and set the cache to the whole source (availableTags). But imagine you have a real request and save the response. It would work fine when using a real source. (the alert doesn't popup when the results are cached and the input doesn't change)

<kbd>[**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/z42Bm/3/)</kbd>

**Updated Code**

```
var cache = {};
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = request.term;
        //check if searched input is in cache and return it as response
        if (term in cache) {
            response(cache[term]);
            return;
        }

        $.getJSON("/echo/json/", request, function (data, status, xhr) {
            alert("Request triggered!");
            //write response in cache
            cache[term] = availableTags;
            response(availableTags);
        });
    },
    minLength: 0
}).focus(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var inputVal = $this.val();
    if (inputVal !== '') {
        $this.autocomplete("search");
    }
});
```

Also mentioned in the comments but here again: [Documentation Entry](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache)

Comment: +1. Good point, it works. Disadvantages: the ajax call is reexecuted.

Comment: Perhaps the [remote cache](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache) functionality would work out? Have no chance to test `autocomplete` with a server side source.

Comment: I just added a updated fiddle. The request doesn't fire if you re-focus the input and the input value is the same. However if you want at max one request just let it fire once and set the response as source like when using `availableTags` as source

Answer (score 0):

I usually populate my text field autocomplete data with a javascript Array object. So on page load, that text field will always have just the specified text for autocomplete. Something like:

```
var contentArray = ["John", "Doe"];
$("#textfieldid").autocomplete({
   source: contentArray
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but I want to help if I can.